# Deserializing a JSON string to a class instance in Haxe

Tags: json, deserialization, haxe

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string into a class instance in Haxe.

```
class Action
{
    public var id:Int;
    public var name:String;

    public function new(id:Int, name:String)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
var action:Action = haxe.Json.parse(actionJson);
trace(action.name);
```

However, this produces an error:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@3431809 to Action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Json doesn't have a mechanism to map language specific data types and only supports a subset of the data types included in JS. To keep the information about the Haxe types you can certainly build your own mechanism.

```
// This works only for basic class instances but you can extend it to work with 
// any type.
// It doesn't work with nested class instances; you can detect the required
// types with macros (will fail for interfaces or extended classes) or keep
// track of the types in the serialized object.
// Also you will have problems with objects that have circular references.

class JsonType {
  public static function encode(o : Dynamic) {
    // to solve some of the issues above you should iterate on all the fields,
    // check for a non-compatible Json type and build a structure like the
    // following before serializing
    return haxe.Json.stringify({
      type : Type.getClassName(Type.getClass(o)),
      data : o
    });
  }

  public static function decode<T>(s : String) : T {
    var o = haxe.Json.parse(s),
        inst = Type.createEmptyInstance(Type.resolveClass(o.type));
    populate(inst, o.data);
    return inst;
  }

  static function populate(inst, data) {
    for(field in Reflect.fields(data)) {
      Reflect.setField(inst, field, Reflect.field(data, field));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: (Three years later) is there a haxelib that handles this?

Comment: Yes, there's at least two, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54504263/2631715

Answer (score 3):

I extended [Franco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074340/can-you-deserialize-a-json-string-to-a-class-instance-with-haxe/11084893#11084893) to allow for recursively containing objects within your json objects, as long as the `_explicitType` property is set on that object.

For instance, the following json:

```
{
   intPropertyExample : 5,
   stringPropertyExample : 'my string',
   pointPropertyExample : {
      _explicitType : 'flash.geom.Point',
      x : 5,
      y : 6
   }
}
```

will correctly be serialized into an object whose class looks like this:

```
import flash.geom.Point;

class MyTestClass
{
   public var intPropertyExample:Int;
   public var stringPropertyExample:String;
   public var pointPropertyExample:Point;
}
```

when calling:

```
var serializedObject:MyTestClass = EXTJsonSerialization.decode([string of json above], MyTestClass)
```

Here's the code (note that it uses [TJSON](https://github.com/martamius/TJSON) as a parser, as [CrazySam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074340/can-you-deserialize-a-json-string-to-a-class-instance-with-haxe/15373807#15373807) recommended):

```
import tjson.TJSON;

class EXTJsonSerialization
{
    public static function encode(o : Dynamic) 
    {
        return TJSON.encode(o);
    }

    public static function decode<T>(s : String, typeClass : Class<Dynamic>) : T 
    {
        var o = TJSON.parse(s);
        var inst = Type.createEmptyInstance(typeClass);
        EXTJsonSerialization.populate(inst, o);
        return inst;
    }

    private static function populate(inst, data) 
    {
        for (field in Reflect.fields(data)) 
        {
            if (field == "_explicitType")
                continue;

            var value = Reflect.field(data, field);
            var valueType = Type.getClass(value);
            var valueTypeString:String = Type.getClassName(valueType);
            var isValueObject:Bool = Reflect.isObject(value) && valueTypeString != "String";
            var valueExplicitType:String = null;

            if (isValueObject)
            {
                valueExplicitType = Reflect.field(value, "_explicitType");
                if (valueExplicitType == null && valueTypeString == "Array")
                    valueExplicitType = "Array";
            }

            if (valueExplicitType != null)
            {
                var fieldInst = Type.createEmptyInstance(Type.resolveClass(valueExplicitType));
                populate(fieldInst, value);
                Reflect.setField(inst, field, fieldInst);
            }
            else
            {
                Reflect.setField(inst, field, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the code above works fine with Flash targets, but for native targets you'll need to do something a bit trickier to handle Arrays. The code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DrSkipper/9042123#file-extjsonserialization-hx) should be able to handle that case.

Answer (score 1):

A modern, macro-based library for this purpose is [**json2object**](https://github.com/elnabo/json2object). It can be used like this:

```
var parser = new json2object.JsonParser<Action>();
var action:Action = parser.fromJson('{"id": 0, "name": "run"}', "action.json");
```

---

Another option, also macro-powered, is [**tink_json**](https://github.com/haxetink/tink_json). In this case it's a bit more verbose because it requires you to specifiy how exactly a class should be parsed using [`@:jsonParse` metadata](https://github.com/haxetink/tink_json#custom-parsers):

```
@:jsonParse(function(json) return new Action(json.id, json.name))
class Action {
// ...
```

Parsing is a one-liner:

```
var action:Action = tink.Json.parse('{"id": 0, "name": "run"}');
```